# Appending tag policy isn't working for some resources

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I'm creating one azure policy to appending tags to newly created resources, it works well for most components, but I found this policy is not working for some components, for example: logic apps.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "parameters": {
    "Environment": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Environment"
      },
      "defaultValue": "dev"
    },
    "Owner": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Owner"
      },
      "defaultValue": "Admin"
    },
    "CostCenter": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "CostCenter"
      },
      "defaultValue": "NA"
    }
  },
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "field": "tags",
      "exists": "false"
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "append",
      "details": [
        {
          "field": "tags",
          "value": {
            "Environment": "[parameters('Environment')]",
            "Owner": "[parameters('Owner')]",
            "CostCenter": "[parameters('CostCenter')]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I added a similar policy to apply tags to resource groups, doesn't working at all, I have no idea what's going on.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "parameters": {
    "Environment": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Environment"
      },
      "defaultValue": "dev"
    },
    "Owner": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Owner"
      },
      "defaultValue": "admin"
    },
    "CostCenter": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "CostCenter"
      },
      "defaultValue": "NA"
    }
  }
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "tags",
          "exists": "false"
        },
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "append",
      "details": [
        {
          "field": "tags",
          "value": {
            "Environment": "[parameters('Environment')]",
            "Owner": "[parameters('Owner')]",
            "CostCenter": "[parameters('CostCenter')]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure it out myself, The `"exists": "false"` condition in my policy will only trigger if the "tags" property is either missing or null, so a resource group or resource with `"tags": {}` will bypass my policy even though it doesn't have any tags.

Besides, the simple checking on tags is not reasonable, should check by tag name from one to another, if not meet, take action to append.

And I also found below statement isn't working for resource groups, maybe because it's irregular practices.

```
{
  "then": {
    "effect": "append",
    "details": [
      {
        "field": "tags",
        "value": {
          "Environment": "[parameters('Environment')]",
          "Owner": "[parameters('Owner')]",
          "CostCenter": "[parameters('CostCenter')]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

suggest using below statement instead

```
{
  "then": {
    "effect": "append",
    "details": [
      {
        "field": "tags['Environment']",
        "value": "[parameters('Environment')]"
      },
      {
        "field": "tags['Owner']",
        "value": "[parameters('Owner')]"
      },
      {
        "field": "tags['CostCenter']",
        "value": "[parameters('CostCenter')]"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: we can also use the built-in policy definitions(`Append tag and its default value`, `Append tag and its value from the resource group` and `Apply tag and its default value to resource groups`) to achieve this goal